# SonataAdminBundle - how to customize admin navbar

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

I have installed `symfony 2.2` and `SonataAdminBundle` .The NavBar for products is looking like this :

```
Dashboard / Product List /{companyName}\{bundleName}\Entity\Product:0000000012fbfd4c00000000c6c10493
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
Dashboard / Product List /{Productname}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I have solution. Only what I needed to do was creating __toString function in entity